# Can Android SplashScreen API be used for non-mobile devices (e.g. TV)

Tags: android, android-tv, android-12, android-splashscreen

The Android documentation does not mention non-mobile platforms in its description of the SplashScreen API. Can this API be used for GoogleTV/Android Native CTV devices?

Are there any special considerations for implementing this on non-mobile app?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen

Comment: None of the other documentation mentions non mobile platforms either.  Unless it says it can't, I would assume it works.  Especially since this is just another activity.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **no**.

An Android developer [filed an issue with Google in Feb 2022](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216374010) asking the same question and this was the response...

> This is intended behaviour. Given the size of the screen on TV devices, we prefer not to show a large icon during app launches and only show a solid colour, same as on previous OS versions. If there's a strong reason to customise the splash screen, please let us know.

The issue was then closed with the status: **Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)**